# jQuery methods not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, addclass

I wrote this simple jQuery `onScroll` function, which adds a class when scrollTop() is bigger than 15. This works 100% in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Of cause this blows up in **IE** and I have no idea why. Could anyone please give advice on this :) thank you. Find my code below.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="promo-header">
 <img src="imgs/promo-header.jpg" alt="" />     
</div>
```

**Scss:**

```
.promo-header {
  background-size: cover;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transition: visibility .3s, height .3s;
  visibility: hidden;
  will-change: visibility, height;

 &.is-hidden {
   height: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
 }
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= 15) {
    $('.promo-header').addClass('is-hidden');
  }
})
```

Comment: which version of jquery and which version of ie?

Comment: Hi @Dekel the jQuery version is 2.2.0 and this is for IE 9 and up.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Provide a working example that demonstrates the problem (you can use jsfiddle/copepen for that).

Comment: Are you sure it is the JavaScript and not the CSS?

Comment: I am positive it's the JS. Trying to find errors in the console is a bit hard, I am using browserstack for IE testing as I currently don't have a windows machine to test. Let me set up a fiddle quick

Comment: Why not use Virtual Box and a free VM from Microsoft?

Comment: when you say it is not working, what exactly is not working?  Does the class get added, if you add logging, does the scroll function get fired?

Comment: Here is a simple example I created quick: https://jsfiddle.net/kimpetersend1/42qkvu8r/3/ it doesn't add the class at all